# Binding in a custom style

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm using a DataGrid with several fixed columns.
Additionally, I'm dynamically adding columns which feature a custom style for their header, containing a `CheckBox`.

Here is the style:

```
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" x:Key="CustomerColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0,3,0" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <CheckBox Margin="0,2,5,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Interpolate"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
            </Style>
```

This is how I add the columns and set their style:

```
                grid.Columns.Add(new CustomDataGridTextColumn()
                {
                    HeaderStyle = (Style)grid.Resources["CustomerColumnHeader"],
                    Header = "Test",
                    IsReadOnly = false,
                    Binding = new Binding(binding),
                    Interpolate = true
                });
```

Edit: Here is what my Column class looks like:

```
class CustomDataGridTextColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    public bool Interpolate { get; set; }
}
```

It's nothing more than a `DataGridTextColumn` with a property added.

How can I bind the `IsChecked` property of the style's `CheckBox` to the `Interpolate` property of my `CustomDataGridTextColumn`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try binding from the `Checkbox.IsChecked` property to your custom column property using a [`RelativeSource Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Try this:

```
<CheckBox Margin="0,2,5,0" IsChecked="{Binding Interpolate, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourXamlPrefix:CustomDataGridTextColumn}}}" />
```

Clearly though, if this works at all, then this will *only* work when the `Style` is applied to an object that has a parent of type `CustomDataGridTextColumn` and you have correctly declared the `YourXamlPrefix` namespace to the CLR namespace of your custom column in the XAML.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've pretty much abandoned my original approach by now, since it has been eating up way too much time. :)